# How to access css classes in typescript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, typescript

Here I want to add CSS classes dynamically to the element using ngClass directive in angular.js.

```
<p [ngClass]="addClasses()">testing content</p>
```

and below is my ts code:

```
isbold: boolean = false;
isItalic: boolean = true;

addClasses() {
   let classes = {
      boldClass: this.isbold,
      italicsClass: this.isItalic
   };
   return classes;
}
```

boldClass and italicsClass are two classes in my css file, these classes should apply depending on the value in the corresponding boolean variables.
But I'm getting the error as Can not find name for both boldClass and italicsClass. Any help appreciated.

Comment: what exactly are you doing? you wan to add either bold or italic class to the <p> tag?

Comment: You don't use `=` in an object literal, you use `:`. So `boldClass: this.isbold`, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your JSON, when you declare a JSON, the properties of it shouldn't be with the "=", try to use something like:

```
addClasses(){
  let classes={
    boldClass: this.isbold,
    italicsClass: this.isItalic
  };
  return classes;
}
```

There was a pending "," after this.isbold, and also, you had this.Italic, and it should be this.isItalic.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can add dynamic classes

```
<p [class.boldClass]="isbold"
   [class.italicsClass]="isItalic">testing content </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Angular's Renderer2

```
@ViewChild('el') element: ElementRef
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
}

addClasses(classes: Array<string>){
  classes.forEach(class => this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'someClass'))

}



 <p #el>testing content </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  isbold: boolean = false;
  isItalic: boolean = true;

  addClasses() {
     let classes = {
       boldClass: this.isbold,
       italicsClass: this.isItalic
     };
     return classes;
   }
}
```

template:

```
<p [ngClass]="addClasses()">testing content </p>
```

css:

```
.boldClass {
   font-weight: bold;
}

.italicsClass {
   font-style: italic;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfk38x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

```
[ngClass]="{'italicsClass':isItalic,'boldClass':isbold}"
```